# Value from BehaviorSubject is not rendered in the subscribed component

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm passing a value from a service to a component using `BehaviorSubject` -

In serviceFile.service.ts:

```js
taskComplete = new BehaviorSubject<{ complete: Boolean; error: any }>(null);
...
this.taskComplete.next({ complete: false, error: error });
...
```

In componentFile.component.ts:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.taskCompleteSub = this.myService.taskComplete.subscribe(
      (data) => {
            this.error = data.error
            ? data.error.error.message
            : null;
          console.log(this.error);
        }
    ); 
}
```

The problem is that the value of property `this.error` is changed and printed in `console.log()`, but this change is not reflected in the component template. In other words, angular does not check this change and re-render.

Comment: The question is how are you using that `this.taskComplete.next()` call in your service. Is that code getting executed at all, after the initial emit? Apparently the call is inside some method. Who is calling that method? Or did you put that inside the `constructor`?

Comment: I put that method inside  a callback

Comment: I think I didn't understand the issue correctly. Is the changed value of `this.error` received and logged in the subscribe method as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your `taskComplete` BehaviorSubject with `null`, so that's the first value emitted. However, in your component you are trying to access `data.error` when data is `null` for the first value emitted. The following should work:

```
this.error = data && data.error && data.error.error
  ? data.error.error.message
  : null;
```

I created this working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fh6cfg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

If `this.myService.taskComplete` is an asynchronous action you'll need to manually trigger change detection.

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

...


ngOnInit() {
    this.taskCompleteSub = this.myService.taskComplete.subscribe(
      (data) => {
            this.error = ...;
            this.cdr.markForCheck();
        }
    ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest two changes.

1. If the default value of the `BehaviourSubject` is `null` and if you're forced to check if the value is `null` in each of it's subscription, you're better off using a `ReplaySubject` with buffer 1 instead. It'll buffer/hold the last value similar to `BehaviorSubject` but doesn't require a default value.
2. If the object's underlying reference hasn't changed, the Angular change detection may detect any changes to re-render the template. In that case try to make a hard-copy using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`.

**Service**

```js
taskComplete = new ReplaySubject<{ complete: Boolean; error: any }>(1);
```

**Component**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.taskCompleteSub = this.myService.taskComplete.subscribe(
    (data) => {
      // `null` check not required here now
      this.error = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.error.error.message));
      console.log(this.error);
    }
  ); 
}
```